# React.js pass multiple json values to one child parameter

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I have a json object:

> "tags": ["salmons","kitchenaccident"]

And I have a Component that parses through the JSON..

```
var entryNodes = this.props.data.data.map(function(entry) {
       return (
         <EntryComponent
             id={entry.user.id}
             img={entry.images.thumbnail.url}
             likes={entry.likes.count}
             link={entry.link}
             username={entry.user.username}
             caption={entry.caption.text}
             tag={entry.tags}/>
       );
```

However, it passes it through as one concatendated string: salmonskitchenaccident.

If I wanted it to render as '#salmons #kitchenaccident'.. what would be the best solution.

```
var EntryComponent = React.createClass({
render: function() {
    return(
            <div className="entry">
                <div className="entry-left">
                    <img className="img-rounded" src={this.props.img} />
                    <div className="like-section">
                        <img className="heart" src="./img/heart.png" />
                        <span className="likes">{this.props.likes}</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="entry-right">
                    <h4><a href={this.props.link}>{this.props.username}</a>    </h4>
                    <p>{this.props.caption}</p>
                    <p className="hash">{this.props.tag}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: This looks ok, but we need to see your `EntryComponent` source code.

Comment: @ffxsam I updated it.

Answer (score 2):

In this line:

`<p className="hash">{this.props.tag}</p>`

you try to display an array straight away, which implicitly calls the `toString()` method of the `tags` array. You need to `map` the  items in your array to HTML nodes, like this:

```
<p className="hash">{this.props.tag.map( tag => (<span>{ '#' + tag }</span>) }</p>
```